.NET 8 Isolated Function app not showing unhandled exception message in Invocation list
We migrated the Azure function in-proc to Isolated in .NET 8.
The following nuget packages are added
<PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
 <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
 <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
 <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>   
 <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />    
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="2.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="2.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.0.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.66.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="Insight.Database" Version="8.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI" Version="1.0.25" />
</ItemGroup>

Below is my HTTP trigger function, which calls a method called "MethodThrowingException" for testing and throws an exception.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace CTSCRMIntegration
{
    public class FuncIntegrationDemo
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FuncIntegrationDemo> _logger;
        private readonly ICMHCCRM _crm;
        public FuncIntegrationDemo(ICMHCCRM crm, ILogger<FuncIntegrationDemo> logger)
        {
            _crm = crm;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("FuncIntegrationDemo")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            string logMessage = string.Empty;


            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //Parse SourceViewName Parameter
            var SourceViewName = req.Query.GetValues("sourceViewName")?.FirstOrDefault();


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceViewName))
            {
                logMessage = "Please pass a Source view name on the query string";
                _logger.LogInformation(logMessage);

                var reqResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                await reqResponse.WriteStringAsync("Please pass a Source view name on the query string");

                return reqResponse;
            }

            //Check for record exists in CRM
            await _crm.MethodThrowingException(SourceViewName);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteStringAsync($"The record successfully synched with CRM !!!");
            return response;

        }
    }
}


The following method is called to throw the exception
public class CMHCCRM : ICMHCCRM
{
    private readonly CRMWebAPIFactory _webApiFactory;

    public async Task MethodThrowingException(string sourceViewName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("The method is not implemented to check the invocation list for blank error message");
    }
}

We added configuration settings in the Program.cs file to enable application settings for the function app. We removed the default behavior of the application settings. The code is as follows:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication().
    ConfigureAppConfiguration(app => {
        app.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options => {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }           
        });

        services.AddScoped<ICMHCCRM, CMHCCRM>(x => new CMHCCRM());

    }).Build();

host.Run()

Here is host.json file
{
  "version": "2.0"  
}

We used ILogger in the function app to log the errors. We haven't used a try-catch block to handle the exception. When any unhandled exception occurs, Invocation list does not show the detail message, it only shows the blank message

The query result returns a blank row if I click on the Run Query in Application Insight.

But if we run the query on the exception table, the exception message is shown in the outerMessage field


Please share the code in text format.

@Ajay Can you provide more details with your code?

@Ajay Please share your code in text format not image and have you able to see the exception details in the Application Insights.

@DasariKamali I am able to see the exceptions in the OuterMessage field as shown in the above screenshot

@Ajay Can you confirm one thing, were you able to get the exception when using the in-process model? Are you not getting the exception after migrating to the Isolated Worker model?

@DasariKamali, when it was in-process model, we were getting the exception in logs but after migration its not working

I successfully retrieved the exception logs in the Azure Function app under Invocations after updating the Program and FuncIntegrationDemo classes in the .NET 8 Isolated HTTP trigger function model.
Program.cs :
I added the following to the Program.cs file to enable GlobalExceptionMiddleware to catch exceptions globally, log them, and return standardized responses.
        services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>();
        services.AddSingleton<IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware, GlobalExceptionMiddleware>();
        services.AddScoped<ICMHCCRM, CMHCCRM>();

Below is the complete Program class.
using FunctionApp14.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware;
using FunctionApp14.Middleware;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
              .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.AddSingleton<TelemetryClient>();
        services.AddSingleton<IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware, GlobalExceptionMiddleware>();
        services.AddScoped<ICMHCCRM, CMHCCRM>();
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();

Functions/FuncIntegrationDemo.cs :
I used the following code to get detailed exception information in the FuncIntegrationDemo class.
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception in FuncIntegrationDemo");
                _logger.LogError($"Exception details: {ex}");

Below is the complete FuncIntegrationDemo class.
using FunctionApp14.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace FunctionApp14
{
    public class FuncIntegrationDemo
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FuncIntegrationDemo> _logger;
        private readonly ICMHCCRM _crm;

        public FuncIntegrationDemo(ICMHCCRM crm, ILogger<FuncIntegrationDemo> logger)
        {
            _crm = crm;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("FuncIntegrationDemo")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            string logMessage = string.Empty;

            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var SourceViewName = req.Query.GetValues("sourceViewName")?.FirstOrDefault();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceViewName))
            {
                logMessage = "Please pass a Source view name on the query string";
                _logger.LogInformation(logMessage);

                var reqResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                await reqResponse.WriteStringAsync("Please pass a Source view name on the query string");

                return reqResponse;
            }
            try
            {
                await _crm.MethodThrowingException(SourceViewName);
                var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                await response.WriteStringAsync($"The record successfully synched with CRM !!!");
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception in FuncIntegrationDemo");
                _logger.LogError($"Exception details: {ex}");

                var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                await errorResponse.WriteStringAsync("An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.");
                return errorResponse;
            }
        }
    }
}

Middleware/GlobalExceptionMiddleware.cs :
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Middleware;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp14.Middleware;
public class GlobalExceptionMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<GlobalExceptionMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public GlobalExceptionMiddleware(ILogger<GlobalExceptionMiddleware> logger, TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception occurred in function execution.");
            var telemetryProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "FunctionName", context.FunctionDefinition.Name },
                { "InvocationId", context.InvocationId }
            };

            _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex, telemetryProperties);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

.csproj :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.66.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Insight.Database" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xrm.Tools.CRMWebAPI" Version="1.0.25" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Azure Function App Invocations :
I successfully retrieved the exception logs in the Azure function app under Invocations.

